# Append filename to output when extracting an xml tag

Tags: powershell, output

I've made a script which extracts the iban tag from multiple xml files , the result is output to a csv file. However I'm having issues with getting the filename out together with the iban value. It is in the $item variable when I write it to screen , when trying to join the two variables in the output I'm not allowed to. Anyone have a tip for me?

[Printscreen of running script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeSJT.png)

```
$items = Get-ChildItem  "C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\\*.xml"  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname 

#Loop over them and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {
        
        [xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content $item
            $IBAN = $XmlDocument.Document.BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn.Ntfctn.Acct.Id 
    write $IBAN
    write $item

    write $filename
    
            
    
    $IBAN  | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

[output after suggested changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emW9D.png)

Comment: Try to check the value of `$IBAN.IBAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct an *object* that will correspond to each record in the resulting CSV file:

```
$items = Get-ChildItem  "C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\\*.xml"  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname 

#Loop over them and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {

    [xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content $item
    $IBAN = $XmlDocument.Document.BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn.Ntfctn.Acct.Id 

    # Create an object with an IBAN property and a FilePath property
    # The resulting CSV file will have the column headers "IBAN" and "FilePath"
    [pscustomobject]@{
      IBAN = $IBAN
      FilePath = $item
    } | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen , thank you very much. So nice with a tip when you are stuck. However for some reason the iban value turned into "System.Xml.XmlElement" in the log file.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/emW9D.png

Comment: @TrondL try `IBAN = $IBAN.IBAN`

Comment: Worked like a charm, a million thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Updated script in case anyone needs it.

$items = Get-ChildItem  "C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\*.xml"  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Fullname

#Loop over them and append them to the document
foreach ($item in $items) {

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content $item
#specify relevant xmltag below
$IBAN = $XmlDocument.Document.BkToCstmrDbtCdtNtfctn.Ntfctn.Acct.Id 
    #write $iban
    
# Create an object with an IBAN property and a FilePath property
# The resulting CSV file will have the column headers "IBAN" and "FilePath"
[pscustomobject]@{
  IBAN = $IBAN.IBAN
  FilePath = $item
} | Export-Csv -path C:\temp\cif01_rda_camt054c\myoutput.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

}